# Implement lapply in conjunction with the get() function to vectorize merge of data tables? R

Tags: r, merge, get, vectorization, lapply

**Question:** How to implement the lapply function in conjunction with the get() function to merge a list of data tables?

**Objective:** For each of the elements in *ticker_name*, merge the data table called *"dt_q_'ticker_name[i]'"* and that called *"meta_'ticker_name[i]'"* by common "id" variable:

```
ticker_name <- c("CTNP", "PB", "SD", "PC", "PE", "TY", "XD") 
for (i in 1:length(ticker_name)) {

  dt <- get(paste0("dt_q_", ticker_name[i]))
  meta <- get(paste0("meta_", ticker_name[i]))
  dt <- merge(x = dt, y = meta, by= c("id"))
  head(dt)
}
```

My non-working attempt with lapply:

```
lapply(
  X = ticker_name,
  FUN = 
    merge(x = get(paste0("dt_q_", ticker_name)),
          y = get(paste0("meta_", ticker_name)), by = c("id")
             ))
```

The error message:

```
 Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
 c("'merge(x = get(paste0(\"dt_q_\", ticker_name)),
 y = get(paste0(\"meta_\", ' is not a function,
 character or symbol", "'    ticker_name)), by = c(\"id\"))'
 is not a function, character or symbol")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return all the objects into a `list` and as the corresponding data.table should be `merge`d, use `Map` which can have multiple arguments

```
Map(merge, mget(paste0("dt_q_", ticker_name)), 
    mget(paste0("meta_", ticker_name)),
        MoreArgs =  list(by = 'id'))
```

---

Or using `lapply`, loop through the 'ticker_name' then `paste` the corresponding 'prefix' part, `get` the values of the string objects and `merge`

```
lapply(ticker_name, function(x) merge(get(paste0("dt_q_", x)), 
      get(paste0("meta_", x)), by = 'id'))
```

NOTE: In the OP's code, after looping through the 'ticker_name' ( or ticker_list - not clear), then it is `paste`ing the prefix with the whole 'ticker_name' which is not the case if we check the `for` loop where it is looping through the sequence of 'ticker_name'.  We can also loop through the sequence

```
lapply(seq_along(ticker_name), function(i) {
  dt <- get(paste0("dt_q_", ticker_name[i]))
  meta <- get(paste0("meta_", ticker_name[i]))
  merge(x = dt, y = meta, by= "id")

     })
```

Comment: Three great answers. Follow-up: In the first option, why do we need to include by = 'id' in a list?